# can't use "src" tag in a proper relative way

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, relative-path

My directory structure is as below.
"--" shows a single level in the folder.

```
--file_uploads
----routes
----views
------index.html
------app.js
------angular.min.js
----public
----node_modules
----app.js
----package.json
```

In the file_uploads folder I open the terminal and write "sudo nodemon app", my server starts running, when I go to "localhost://3000" I get two errors i.e. "error 404 cannot find angular.min.js" and "error 404 cannot find app.js".

In my index.html I have these two lines of code for source "src" :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./views/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="./views/app.js"></script>
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong, my index.html page opens but couldn't find the relative path to angular.min.js and app.js.

Ok, I got a solution to sever files from http-server, but i need that with my express I could be able to server html code along with angularjs code. How can I achieve express+node+angular+html?

In my app.js servers-side I am doing this.

```
var cons = require('consolidate');

// view engine setup
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname+ "/views"));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/profile',profile);
```

And when it comes to index.js I do this :-

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index.html');
});
```

PS, MY SERVER IS PROPERLY RENDERING TO index.html.

Comment: If your views folder is being served correctly, you should be loading your files like `/angular.min.js` and `app.js`

Comment: In index.html I have written content that is being displayed, means index.html works, "/angular.min.js" and "/app.js" isn't working though.

Comment: You need to provide the source of the relevant parts of your server, namely the part that serves static files. This doesn't happen automatically, and you usually specify the root folder for your documents.

Comment: @jcaron please see the question now as I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, since you're using express

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

This will serve ALL files within the public folder. Place your  `/angular.min.js` and `/app.js` in there and your index.html should pick them up. Of course, you can choose to serve the views folder but the index.html in there might clash.

Make sure scripts are pointing from root e.g. `/angular.min.js` and `/app.js`

1. Install: npm install -g http-server.
2. cd into `views`
3. run `http-server`
4. go to `http://localhost:8080/` in browser

Nodemon is used to serve a server file not client files like you're trying to serve.

Comment: Then nodemon will run for my nodejs code and http-server -o for my angular and html code concurrently?

Comment: @AsimRaja You'll want to use express and serve the files whilst running your server code concurrently. Unless you don't do server side rendering. Then just use the example above.

Comment: Well, I am doing server side rendering. I can't find a soultion to this problem that my nodemon running could server .min.js and app.js file.

Comment: Where is your server.js or entry point for your server code I don't see any server side rendering traces in your project folder.

Comment: I am entering through "app.js" residing in file_uploads my main folder. Plus please see the question now as I have edited it.

Comment: You are the savior.